# Compiling Opus 1.1-rc2 for iOS with XCode 5

Tags: ios, neon, opus

I'm trying to compile Opus 1.1-rc2 with ARM NEON optimizations for iOS.

Here is the configure that I am using :

```
export CC="xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7"
export CCAS="xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -no-integrated-as"
./configure --enable-fixed-point \
            --disable-doc \
            --disable-extra-programs \
            --with-sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk \
            --host=arm-apple-darwin
```

If I use `--disable-asm`, everything compiles gloriously :) But I do want the ARM NEON optimizations, so I don't want to put the flag. And here come the troubles :

Without `-no-integrated-as`, I get:

```
libtool: compile:  xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../opus-1.1-rc -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/include -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/celt -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/silk -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/silk/float -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/silk/fixed -g -O2 -MT celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.lo -MD -MP -MF celt/arm/.deps/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.Tpo -c celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S  -fno-common -DPIC -o celt/arm/.libs/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.o
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:29:24: error: unknown directive
    .text; .p2align 2; .arch armv7-a
                       ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:30:4: error: unknown directive
   .fpu neon
   ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:31:4: error: unknown directive
   .object_arch armv4t
   ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:255:2: error: unknown directive
 .type xcorr_kernel_neon, %function; xcorr_kernel_neon: @ PROC
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:316:2: error: unknown directive
 .size xcorr_kernel_neon, .-xcorr_kernel_neon @ ENDP
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:318:2: error: unknown directive
 .type celt_pitch_xcorr_neon, %function; celt_pitch_xcorr_neon: @ PROC
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:362:14: error: invalid variant ''
  CMP r8, r4@
             ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:405:2: error: unknown directive
 .size celt_pitch_xcorr_neon, .-celt_pitch_xcorr_neon @ ENDP
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:414:2: error: unknown directive
 .type xcorr_kernel_edsp, %function; xcorr_kernel_edsp: @ PROC
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:466:3: error: invalid instruction
  LDRGTH r14, [r4], #2 @ r14 = *x++
  ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:476:3: error: invalid instruction
  LDRGTH r12, [r4], #2 @ r12 = *x++
  ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:484:3: error: invalid instruction
  LDRGTH r14, [r4] @ r14 = *x
  ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:494:2: error: unknown directive
 .size xcorr_kernel_edsp, .-xcorr_kernel_edsp @ ENDP
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:496:2: error: unknown directive
 .type celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp, %function; celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp: @ PROC
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:577:3: error: invalid instruction
  LDRGEH r6, [r4], #2
  ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:578:3: error: invalid instruction
  LDRGEH r8, [r5], #2
  ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:596:2: error: unknown directive
 .size celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp, .-celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp @ ENDP
 ^
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:601:23: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
    .section .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
                      ^
```

With `-no-integrated-as`, I get:

```
libtool: compile:  xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -no-integrated-as -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../opus-1.1-rc -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/include -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/celt -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/silk -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/silk/float -I../../../opus-1.1-rc/silk/fixed -g -O2 -MT celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.lo -MD -MP -MF celt/arm/.deps/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.Tpo -c celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S  -fno-common -DPIC -o celt/arm/.libs/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.o
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:29:Unknown pseudo-op: .arch
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:29:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 97 (a).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:30:Unknown pseudo-op: .fpu
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:30:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 110 (n).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:31:Unknown pseudo-op: .object_arch
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:31:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 97 (a).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:36:Unknown pseudo-op: .global
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:36:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 99 (c).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:40:Unknown pseudo-op: .global
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:40:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 99 (c).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:255:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:255:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 120 (x).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:273:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d3},[r1]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:274:bad instruction `SUB r3,r2,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:275:bad instruction `MOVS r3,r3,lsr#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:276:bad instruction `BEQ xcorr_kernel_neon_process4_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:281:bad instruction `SUBS r3,r3,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:282:bad instruction `VLD1.16 d4,[r1]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:283:bad instruction `VLD1.16 d2,[r0]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:284:bad instruction `VEXT.16 d5,d3,d4,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:285:bad instruction `VEXT.16 d6,d3,d4,#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:286:bad instruction `VEXT.16 d7,d3,d4,#3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:288:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d3,d2[0]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:289:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d5,d2[1]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:290:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d6,d2[2]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:291:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d7,d2[3]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:293:bad instruction `VMOV.S16 d3,d4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:295:bad instruction `BNE xcorr_kernel_neon_process4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:299:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d2[]},[r0]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:301:bad instruction `SUB r3,r2,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:302:bad instruction `ANDS r3,r3,#3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:303:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d3,d2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:304:bad instruction `BEQ xcorr_kernel_neon_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:307:bad instruction `SUBS r3,r3,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:308:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d4[]},[r1]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:309:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d2[]},[r0]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:310:bad instruction `VEXT.16 d3,d3,d4,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:311:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d3,d2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:312:bad instruction `BNE xcorr_kernel_neon_process_remaining'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:315:bad instruction `MOV pc,lr'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:316:Unknown pseudo-op: .size
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:316:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 120 (x).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:318:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:318:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 99 (c).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:328:bad instruction `STMFD sp!,{r4-r9,lr}'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:330:bad instruction `LDR r4,[sp,#28]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:331:bad instruction `MOV r5,r0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:332:bad instruction `MOV r6,r1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:333:bad instruction `MOV r7,r2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:334:bad instruction `MOV r2,r3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:336:bad instruction `VMOV.S32 d16,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:337:bad instruction `MOV r8,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:338:bad instruction `CMP r4,#3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:339:bad instruction `BLE celt_pitch_xcorr_neon_process4_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:341:bad instruction `SUB r9,r4,#3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:344:bad instruction `MOV r0,r5'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:345:bad instruction `ADD r1,r6,r8,LSL#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:346:bad instruction `VMOV.I32 q0,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:350:bad instruction `BL xcorr_kernel_neon'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:352:bad instruction `VST1.32 {q0},[r7]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:353:bad instruction `VPMAX.S32 d0,d0,d1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:354:bad instruction `ADD r8,r8,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:355:bad instruction `VPMAX.S32 d0,d0,d0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:356:bad instruction `CMP r8,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:357:bad instruction `VMAX.S32 d16,d16,d0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:359:bad instruction `BLT celt_pitch_xcorr_neon_process4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:362:bad instruction `CMP r8,r4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:363:bad instruction `BGE celt_pitch_xcorr_neon_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:366:bad instruction `MOV r0,r5'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:367:bad instruction `ADD r1,r6,r8,LSL#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:368:bad instruction `VMOV.I32 q0,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:369:bad instruction `MOVS r3,r2,LSR#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:370:bad instruction `BEQ inner_loop_neon_process4_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:373:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d2},[r0]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:374:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d3},[r1]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:375:bad instruction `SUBS r3,r3,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:376:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d2,d3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:377:bad instruction `BNE inner_loop_neon_process4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:379:bad instruction `VPADD.S32 d0,d0,d1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:380:bad instruction `VPADD.S32 d0,d0,d0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:383:bad instruction `ANDS r3,r2,#3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:384:bad instruction `BEQ inner_loop_neon_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:387:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d2[]},[r0]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:388:bad instruction `VLD1.16 {d3[]},[r1]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:389:bad instruction `SUBS r3,r3,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:390:bad instruction `VMLAL.S16 q0,d2,d3'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:391:bad instruction `BNE inner_loop_neon_process_remaining'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:394:bad instruction `VST1.32 {d0[0]},[r7]!'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:395:bad instruction `VMAX.S32 d16,d16,d0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:397:bad instruction `ADD r8,r8,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:398:bad instruction `CMP r8,r4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:399:bad instruction `BCC celt_pitch_xcorr_neon_process_remaining'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:402:bad instruction `VMOV d0,d16'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:403:bad instruction `VMOV.32 r0,d0[0]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:404:bad instruction `LDMFD sp!,{r4-r9,pc}'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:405:Unknown pseudo-op: .size
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:405:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 99 (c).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:414:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:414:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 120 (x).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:427:bad instruction `STMFD sp!,{r2,r4,r5,lr}'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:428:bad instruction `SUBS r2,r3,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:429:bad instruction `LDRD r10,r11,[r5],#8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:430:bad instruction `BLE xcorr_kernel_edsp_process4_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:431:bad instruction `LDR r12,[r4],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:437:bad instruction `SMLABB r6,r12,r10,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:438:bad instruction `LDR r14,[r4],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:439:bad instruction `SMLABT r7,r12,r10,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:440:bad instruction `SUBS r2,r2,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:441:bad instruction `SMLABB r8,r12,r11,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:442:bad instruction `SMLABT r9,r12,r11,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:443:bad instruction `SMLATT r6,r12,r10,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:444:bad instruction `LDR r10,[r5],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:445:bad instruction `SMLATB r7,r12,r11,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:446:bad instruction `SMLATT r8,r12,r11,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:447:bad instruction `SMLATB r9,r12,r10,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:448:bad instruction `LDRGT r12,[r4],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:449:bad instruction `SMLABB r6,r14,r11,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:450:bad instruction `SMLABT r7,r14,r11,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:451:bad instruction `SMLABB r8,r14,r10,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:452:bad instruction `SMLABT r9,r14,r10,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:453:bad instruction `SMLATT r6,r14,r11,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:454:bad instruction `LDR r11,[r5],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:455:bad instruction `SMLATB r7,r14,r10,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:456:bad instruction `SMLATT r8,r14,r10,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:457:bad instruction `SMLATB r9,r14,r11,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:458:bad instruction `BGT xcorr_kernel_edsp_process4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:460:bad instruction `ADDS r2,r2,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:461:bad instruction `BLE xcorr_kernel_edsp_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:462:bad instruction `LDRH r12,[r4],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:463:bad instruction `SUBS r2,r2,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:465:bad instruction `SMLABB r6,r12,r10,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:466:bad instruction `LDRGTH r14,[r4],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:467:bad instruction `SMLABT r7,r12,r10,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:468:bad instruction `SMLABB r8,r12,r11,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:469:bad instruction `SMLABT r9,r12,r11,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:470:bad instruction `BLE xcorr_kernel_edsp_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:471:bad instruction `SMLABT r6,r14,r10,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:472:bad instruction `SUBS r2,r2,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:473:bad instruction `SMLABB r7,r14,r11,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:474:bad instruction `LDRH r10,[r5],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:475:bad instruction `SMLABT r8,r14,r11,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:476:bad instruction `LDRGTH r12,[r4],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:477:bad instruction `SMLABB r9,r14,r10,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:478:bad instruction `BLE xcorr_kernel_edsp_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:479:bad instruction `SMLABB r6,r12,r11,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:480:bad instruction `CMP r2,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:481:bad instruction `SMLABT r7,r12,r11,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:482:bad instruction `LDRH r2,[r5],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:483:bad instruction `SMLABB r8,r12,r10,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:484:bad instruction `LDRGTH r14,[r4]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:485:bad instruction `SMLABB r9,r12,r2,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:486:bad instruction `BLE xcorr_kernel_edsp_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:487:bad instruction `SMLABT r6,r14,r11,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:488:bad instruction `LDRH r11,[r5]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:489:bad instruction `SMLABB r7,r14,r10,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:490:bad instruction `SMLABB r8,r14,r2,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:491:bad instruction `SMLABB r9,r14,r11,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:493:bad instruction `LDMFD sp!,{r2,r4,r5,pc}'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:494:Unknown pseudo-op: .size
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:494:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 120 (x).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:496:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:496:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 99 (c).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:513:bad instruction `STMFD sp!,{r4-r11,lr}'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:514:bad instruction `MOV r5,r1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:515:bad instruction `LDR r1,[sp,#36]'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:516:bad instruction `MOV r4,r0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:518:bad instruction `MOV r0,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:520:bad instruction `SUBS r1,r1,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:521:bad instruction `BLT celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp_process4_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:525:bad instruction `MOV r6,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:526:bad instruction `MOV r7,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:527:bad instruction `MOV r8,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:528:bad instruction `MOV r9,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:529:bad instruction `BL xcorr_kernel_edsp'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:531:bad instruction `CMP r0,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:533:bad instruction `ADD r5,r5,#8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:534:bad instruction `MOVLT r0,r6'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:535:bad instruction `CMP r0,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:536:bad instruction `STRD r6,r7,[r2],#8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:537:bad instruction `MOVLT r0,r7'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:538:bad instruction `CMP r0,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:539:bad instruction `STRD r8,r9,[r2],#8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:540:bad instruction `MOVLT r0,r8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:541:bad instruction `CMP r0,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:542:bad instruction `MOVLT r0,r9'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:543:bad instruction `SUBS r1,r1,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:544:bad instruction `BGE celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp_process4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:546:bad instruction `ADDS r1,r1,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:547:bad instruction `BLE celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:550:bad instruction `SUBS r12,r3,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:552:bad instruction `MOV r14,#0'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:553:bad instruction `BLT celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp_process_remaining_loop_done'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:554:bad instruction `LDRD r6,r7,[r4],#8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:555:bad instruction `LDRD r8,r9,[r5],#8'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:558:bad instruction `SMLABB r14,r6,r8,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:559:bad instruction `SUBS r12,r12,#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:560:bad instruction `SMLATT r14,r6,r8,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:561:bad instruction `LDRGE r6,[r4],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:562:bad instruction `SMLABB r14,r7,r9,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:563:bad instruction `LDRGE r8,[r5],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:564:bad instruction `SMLATT r14,r7,r9,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:565:bad instruction `LDRGE r7,[r4],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:566:bad instruction `LDRGE r9,[r5],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:567:bad instruction `BGE celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp_process_remaining_loop4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:569:bad instruction `ADDS r12,r12,#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:570:bad instruction `LDRGE r6,[r4],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:571:bad instruction `LDRGE r8,[r5],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:573:bad instruction `SMLABBGE r14,r6,r8,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:574:bad instruction `SUBGE r12,r12,#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:575:bad instruction `SMLATTGE r14,r6,r8,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:576:bad instruction `ADDS r12,r12,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:577:bad instruction `LDRGEH r6,[r4],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:578:bad instruction `LDRGEH r8,[r5],#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:580:bad instruction `SUB r4,r4,r3,LSL#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:582:bad instruction `SMLABBGE r14,r6,r8,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:584:bad instruction `SUB r5,r5,r3,LSL#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:587:bad instruction `CMP r0,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:588:bad instruction `ADD r5,r5,#2'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:589:bad instruction `MOVLT r0,r14'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:590:bad instruction `SUBS r1,r1,#1'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:592:bad instruction `STR r14,[r2],#4'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:593:bad instruction `BGT celt_pitch_xcorr_edsp_process_remaining'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:595:bad instruction `LDMFD sp!,{r4-r11,pc}'
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:596:Unknown pseudo-op: .size
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:596:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 99 (c).
celt/arm/celt_pitch_xcorr_arm-gnu.S:601:unknown section type: %progbits
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So what should I do to compile Opus with ASM NEON optimizations for iOS ?

(BTW, compiling Opus with ASM Neon optims for Android was very easy and straightforward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known build issues with the new Neon assembly. For now, the best thing to do in case of problem is to configure with --disable-rtcd.

Comment: This certainly doesn't fix this issue for me, is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the non-integrated assembly errors (and the `-gnu` filename), I'd say this was written for gas rather than llvm, which is why you're probably compiling fine for Android (you're probably using gas there, aren't you?)

I'd recommend trying the [gas-preprocessor.pl](https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor/blob/master/gas-preprocessor.pl) script to convert this code first. It's designed to convert the ffmpeg code to work with Apple's old gas assembler, so it will probably get it closer to where you need for LLVM. You may still need to go through and lowercase the instructions, though.

You could also try compiling this with GCC into a static library. You could also google for "opus ios." It looks like [others have attacked this problem](https://github.com/zimuliu/opus-ios-build) (not sure if that script actually works for this, but it's a start).

Comment: I have already looked into this project. It works with Opus 1.0.x, hence, without the ARM NEON optims

Comment: As for gas-preprocessor, it transforms all the 600 lines ASM file to 7 lines. I know nothing about assembly language, but I seriously doubt that's correct...